# SQL ''SUM OVER PARTITION BY'' command gets different result from raw data

Tags: sql, sum, window-functions

I'm really struggling with my query of `SUM OVER PARTITION BY`.

I have a table named as entity_table:

```
---------------------------------
entity_id    other_attributes...
    1            xxxx
    2            xxxx
    3            xxxx
---------------------------------
```

and another table named as score_table

```
-------------------------------
entity_id    score    date
    1          0      20170101
    1          5      20170101
    2          5      20170101
    2          0      20170101
    3          5      20170101
-------------------------------
```

and my query is as below:

```
select someother_attributes
,      total_score = sum(score) over (partition by entity_id)
,      more_other_attributes
from entity_table
left join score_table
on entity_table.entity_id = score_table.entity_id
where date = 20170101
```

In order to confirm I've got the correct results from above query, I took some spot test. For example, for entity_id = 10:

```
select * from score_table where date = 20170101
```

and the results are

```
--------------------------------
entity_id     score    date
    10          0      20170101
    10          5      20170101
    10          0      20170101
    10          0      20170101
    10          5      20170101
--------------------------------
```

so the sum of score is 10. Then I take the corresponding entity in my big query, I've found the sum is 30. This is obviously incorrect.

Could anyone help me out please? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First guess is that `entity_table` has three rows for `10`.  You should also tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You should add some data sample, and the expected result, just to check why is not working.

Comment: What do you get when you run `select sum(score) from from entity_table
left join score_table
on entity_table.entity_id = score_table.entity_id
where date = 20170101 and entity_table.entity_id = 10` ?